# Worklight Facebook app error: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

Tags: javascript, facebook, ibm-mobilefirst

I've follow this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#loading , this is code in common/myapp.html in my IBM Worklight app:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Buy3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Buy3.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <!--application UI goes here-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxx', // App ID
    channelUrl : 'http://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
    oauth: true
  });


  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
   (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      //Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    });
  }
</script>
<!--Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to-->
<!--present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.-->
<div id="user-info"></div>
<button id="fb-auth" onclick="FB.login();" >Login</button>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Buy3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Here are some of the values from my Facebook Application configuration:

```
App ID: "XXX"
Display Name: "[blah blah blah]"
Namespace: jfgjfgjhfgjh
App domains:stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com
HostingURL: https://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com
Sandbox Mode: "Disable"
Site Url: http://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/
Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/jfgjfgjhfgjh
Canvas URL: http://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/
Secure Canvas URL: https://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/
Page Tab URL: http://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/
Secure Page Tab URL: https://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/
```

Notice that I had to change the js.src parameter near the bottom of the code from the example given in the tutorial same with parameter in my channel file.

Then when i click login button i seen facebook Login Dialog,i've put email and password then click ok and i've got error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the Apps domains.

I've search everything on stackoverflow and google but can't solve this error.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What value are you using for the redirect_uri parameter? is it on stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com? If not, that's exactly what the error message means

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Worklight - config app facebook to run in real device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546357/ibm-worklight-config-app-facebook-to-run-in-real-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've got it,just remove every things about heroku, then app config  like this

```
App domains:localhost
HostingURL: 
Sandbox Mode: "Disable"
Site Url: http://localhost/
Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/jfgjfgjhfgjh
Canvas URL: http://localhost/
Secure Canvas URL: https://localhost/
Page Tab URL: http://localhost/
Secure Page Tab URL: https://localhost/
```

Then

> `//channelUrl : 'http://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/channel.html'`

in HTML.
For anyone need it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this will work with localhost there, when outside users will try to reach the application, but if you say this is supposed to work with teh channelUrl... ok. Please mark this answer as Answered. Thanks.